# scanf formatted input does not apply to first character scanned

Tags: c, formatting, scanf

I'm trying to write a program that outputs non-vowel characters (without if statements and using formatted scanf input). The code I currently have does not apply the %*[] ignored characters to the first %c character scanned, but the restriction applies for the other characters. For example, "Andrew" becomes "Andrw" instead of "ndrw". I'm suspecting this could be due to the %c at the beginning. Could someone help me please? :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char c;
    while (scanf("%c%*[aeiouAEIOU]", &c) == 1)
        printf("%c", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scanf formats are matched in **order** so `%c` is matched **first** for the `A`. You need to use 2 **separate** scanfs for this, or precede the loop with the initial-vowel eating scanf:

```
scanf("%*[aeiouAEIOU]");
while (scanf("%c%*[aeiouAEIOU]", &c) == 1) { 
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

The question is is this any clearer and better than

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (! strchr("aeiouAEIOU", c)) {
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

I have an opinionated answer...

Comment: Very clear explanation, thank you very much! Part of the challenge was to only use scanf and printf as well ahaha